# Multivalue parameter not working in SSRS report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

First I would like to apologize for any mistake and misuse of the English language as it is not my natural language.

On the report i have 3 specify values(value: 1,2,3) and each value is show different table when i choose one value from the list I got expected results, but If I choose multi values(1,2) the results are only show the table but no data.(not got an error.)

any one can give advise?thank a lot.

```html
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spIVDiscreAddrDataFolUpList]

@iList  varchar(10) = '1,2'
as

BEGIN
SELECT 
'0' as iList,

pn.No_,
[Address Code]                 = pn.[Address Code],
[Contact]                      = pn.[Phone No_],
[Partner Name]                 = pn.[Name],
[Partner Name 2]               = pn.[Name 2],
[PledgeType] = pdl.[PledgeType],
[Address]            = pn.[Address]


INTO #Temp110
FROM dbo.[Product Line] pdl  WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN [Pledges] pl   WITH (NOLOCK) 
ON pdl.[Pledge ID]=pl.ID
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Contact] pn with (NOLOCK)
on pdl.[No_] = pn.No_
LEFT join [dbo].[Country_Region] co WITH (NOLOCK)  
on pn.[Country_Region Code] = co.Code
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    
    cast(Value as int) as Code,
    Value2 as Description
    FROM Config WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE 
    Category='Children'
    AND SubCategory='Status'
    AND DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),ISNULL(ObsoleteDate,DATEADD(dd,1,GETDATE())))>0
) childstatus
on c.StatusID = childstatus.Code


END





--------------------------------------- @ListA------------------------------------------



IF @iList='1' --ListA
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Temp110
SELECT 
--iList = CAST (@iList as int ) ,
@iList as iList,
pn.No_,
[Address Code]                 = pn.[Address Code],
[Contact]                      = pn.[Phone No_],
[Partner Name]                 = pn.[Name],
[Partner Name 2]               = pn.[Name 2],
[PledgeType] = pdl.[PledgeType],
[Address]            = pn.[Address]

INTO #Temp110
FROM dbo.[Product Line] pdl  WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN [Pledges] pl   WITH (NOLOCK) 
ON pdl.[Pledge ID]=pl.ID
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Contact] pn with (NOLOCK)
on pdl.[No_] = pn.No_
LEFT join [dbo].[Country_Region] co WITH (NOLOCK)  
on pn.[Country_Region Code] = co.Code
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    
    cast(Value as int) as Code,
    Value2 as Description
    FROM Config WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE 
    Category='Children'
    AND SubCategory='Status'
    AND DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),ISNULL(ObsoleteDate,DATEADD(dd,1,GETDATE())))>0
) childstatus
on c.StatusID = childstatus.Code

WHERE  
(pdl.[Pledge Status] = '2' and c.StatusID ='4')
or (pdl.[Pledge Status] = '2' and c.StatusID ='7')  

END


-------------ListB---------------------

IF @iList='2' --ListB
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Temp110
SELECT 
--iList = CAST (@iList as int ) ,
@iList as iList,
pn.No_,
[Address Code]                 = pn.[Address Code],
[Contact]                      = pn.[Phone No_],
[Partner Name]                 = pn.[Name],
[Partner Name 2]               = pn.[Name 2],
[PledgeType] = pdl.[PledgeType],

[Address]            = pn.[Address]
INTO #Temp110
FROM dbo.[Product Line] pdl  WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN [Pledges] pl   WITH (NOLOCK) 
ON pdl.[Pledge ID]=pl.ID
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Contact] pn with (NOLOCK)
on pdl.[No_] = pn.No_
LEFT join [dbo].[Country_Region] co WITH (NOLOCK)  
on pn.[Country_Region Code] = co.Code
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    
    cast(Value as int) as Code,
    Value2 as Description
    FROM Config WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE 
    Category='Children'
    AND SubCategory='Status'
    AND DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),ISNULL(ObsoleteDate,DATEADD(dd,1,GETDATE())))>0
) childstatus
on c.StatusID = childstatus.Code

WHERE  
(pdl.[Pledge Status] = '2' and c.StatusID ='3')
or (pdl.[Pledge Status] = '2' and c.StatusID ='6')  

END





select * from #Temp110 where iList in (@iList)
Drop Table #Temp110
```

Comment: Can you share your SQL queries?

Comment: how to share query to you?/3\

Comment: That's not only to me, but to other community members to give a context on the problem; you should be able to edit your request and post the query there